directory will not accept file/folder with a certain name
iMac, MacOS12.7.2, file system on both source and destination discs are APFS
I have been trying to copy a big folder (2TB) with many subfolders and run into errors because in some (fewer than .5%) folders/files cannot be copied.
For example, I have a folder in home directory called "John Finnemore". I try to move it into my chosen target directory and hit an error.
%  mv ~/John\ Finnemore .
mv: rename /Users/stephenb/John Finnemore to ./John Finnemore: No such file or directory

However, if I move and change its name in the target directory, no problem:
%  mv ~/John\ Finnemore ./JF
%  ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  7 stephenb  staff   224 Apr 26 09:00 .
drwxr-xr-x  8 stephenb  staff   256 Apr 25 15:12 ..
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 stephenb  staff  8196 Apr 26 09:01 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x  4 stephenb  staff   128 Apr 26 08:57 JF
drwxr-xr-x  9 stephenb  staff   288 Apr 25 18:38 temp folder

But if I subsequently try to change it back to its desired name - problem:
%  mv ./JF ./John\ Finnemore
mv: rename ./JF to ./John Finnemore: No such file or directory

The issue is the same trying to use the finder to copy/move the folder. An error message appears:
The operation can’t be completed because one or more required items can’t be found.
(Error code -43)
Why are some filenames apparently banned?   I thought it might be to do with the length of the path, but I think not because if I have been able to move the folder and give at an even longer name.
Any suggestions?
EDIT
I do not think the issue is to do with spaces, another name giving problems is Boon
%  mkdir Boon
mkdir: .: No such file or directory
%  ls -al ./Boon
ls: ./Boon: No such file or directory
%  mkdir t1
%  mv t1 Boon
mv: rename t1 to Boon: No such file or directory


https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448257/how-to-rename-a-file-that-contains-spaces-in-terminal

Does this answer your question? Batch rename photos by creation date on Mac OS X using Bash not working with spaces
